# ENABLE user ROLES in KIBANA and Elasticsearch using DOCKER.compose?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, xpath, docker-compose, kibana

Below is my docker.compose.yml file that starts Elasticsearch 6.2.4 with 2 nodes + Kibana 6.2.4.

I am using Elastisearch 6.2.4 platinum version and I have configured user login and password across ELK.

The problem is that when I log into Kibana>Management I don't see the panel to configure Security and User roles, even after having configured all that. (Picture 1 attached here -> [Kibana pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzip8.png))

I need to configure a user which has a role that allows only to read dashboards - dashboard user with read only permission.

Please help.  How can I do this?!

```
    version: '2.2'

    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
          - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
          - cluster.name=docker-cluster
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - xpack.security.enabled=true
          - xpack.ml.enabled=true
          - xpack.watcher.enabled=true
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
          - 32769:9200
          - 32770:9300
        networks:
          - esnet

      elasticsearch2:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
        container_name: elasticsearch2
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
          - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
          - cluster.name=docker-cluster
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
          - xpack.security.enabled=true
          - xpack.ml.enabled=true
          - xpack.watcher.enabled=true     
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        networks:
          - esnet

      kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
        container_name: kibana
        volumes:
          - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://elasticsearch:9200"
          - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
          - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=MagicWord
        links:
          - elasticsearch
        ports: 
          - 32771:5601
        volumes:
          - esdata3:/usr/share/kibana
        networks: 
          - esnet
        depends_on: 
          - elasticsearch  

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
  esdata3:
    driver: local


networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge
```

kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
#server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy. This only affects
# the URLs generated by Kibana, your proxy is expected to remove the basePath value before forwarding requests
# to Kibana. This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

xpack.security.enabled: true
```

[image]

LOG

```
  PS C:\Users\C0> cd documents/docker
    PS C:\Users\C0\documents\docker> docker-compose up
    Creating network "docker_esnet" with driver "bridge"
    Creating elasticsearch2 ... done
    Creating elasticsearch  ... done
    Creating kibana         ... done
    Attaching to elasticsearch2, elasticsearch, kibana

.
...
.....


    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:31,189][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.39xvr3ne, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,776][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [analysis-common]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [ingest-common]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [lang-expression]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [lang-mustache]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,778][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [lang-painless]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,778][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [mapper-extras]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,778][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [parent-join]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,779][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [percolator]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,779][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [rank-eval]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,780][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [reindex]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,780][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [repository-url]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,781][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [transport-netty4]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,782][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded module [tribe]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,783][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,783][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,784][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-core]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,784][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-deprecation]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,784][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-graph]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-logstash]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-ml]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-monitoring]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-security]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,789][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-upgrade]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,789][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [obWycXg] loaded plugin [x-pack-watcher]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,828][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [analysis-common]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [ingest-common]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [lang-expression]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [lang-mustache]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [lang-painless]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [mapper-extras]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [parent-join]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [percolator]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,829][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [rank-eval]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [reindex]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [repository-url]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [transport-netty4]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,830][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded module [tribe]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-core]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-deprecation]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-graph]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-logstash]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-ml]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-monitoring]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-security]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,831][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-upgrade]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:35,832][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [fJor1LC] loaded plugin [x-pack-watcher]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:43,096][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/126] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 6.2.4 (Build 524e7fe231abc1) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:43,115][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/126] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 6.2.4 (Build 524e7fe231abc1) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:46,547][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [obWycXg] using discovery type [zen]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:46,581][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [fJor1LC] using discovery type [zen]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,136][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,136][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [obWycXg] starting ...
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,316][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,316][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [fJor1LC] starting ...
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,486][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [obWycXg] publish_address {172.20.0.3:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,545][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [obWycXg] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,617][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [fJor1LC] publish_address {172.20.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:48,705][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [fJor1LC] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,848][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [fJor1LC] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,857][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [fJor1LC] new_master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,894][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [fJor1LC] zen-disco-node-join[{obWycXg}{obWycXgmRx2fKdDKeYQAKA}{WIC48jIVQQiN8CMuPgznqg}{172.20.0.3}{172.20.0.3:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}], reason: added {{obWycXg}{obWycXgmRx2fKdDKeYQAKA}{WIC48jIVQQiN8CMuPgznqg}{172.20.0.3}{172.20.0.3:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true},}
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,911][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [obWycXg] detected_master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, added {{fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true},}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [2]])
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,926][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [fJor1LC] added {{obWycXg}{obWycXgmRx2fKdDKeYQAKA}{WIC48jIVQQiN8CMuPgznqg}{172.20.0.3}{172.20.0.3:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true},}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [2] source [zen-disco-node-join[{obWycXg}{obWycXgmRx2fKdDKeYQAKA}{WIC48jIVQQiN8CMuPgznqg}{172.20.0.3}{172.20.0.3:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}]]])
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,928][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ElectMasterService] [fJor1LC] value for setting "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" is too low. This can result in data loss! Please set it to at least a quorum of master-eligible nodes (current value: [1], total number of master-eligible nodes used for publishing in this round: [2])
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:51,995][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [obWycXg] publish_address {172.20.0.3:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:52,008][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [fJor1LC] publish_address {172.20.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:52,016][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [obWycXg] started
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:52,017][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [fJor1LC] started
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:52,975][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.TokenService   ] [obWycXg] refresh keys
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,397][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.TokenService   ] [obWycXg] refreshed keys
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,406][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [obWycXg] license [cb110a0f-9082-4077-901f-52ec7519e4a6] mode [basic] - valid
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,952][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [obWycXg] master_left [{fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}], reason [failed to ping, tried [3] times, each with  maximum [30s] timeout]
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,953][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [obWycXg] master left (reason = failed to ping, tried [3] times, each with  maximum [30s] timeout), current nodes: nodes:
    elasticsearch     |    {obWycXg}{obWycXgmRx2fKdDKeYQAKA}{WIC48jIVQQiN8CMuPgznqg}{172.20.0.3}{172.20.0.3:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, local
    elasticsearch     |    {fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, master
    elasticsearch     |
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,960][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherService   ] [obWycXg] stopping watch service, reason [no master node]
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,972][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [fJor1LC] license [cb110a0f-9082-4077-901f-52ec7519e4a6] mode [basic] - valid
    elasticsearch2    | [2018-04-25T16:50:54,006][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [fJor1LC] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
    elasticsearch     | [2018-04-25T16:50:53,962][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [obWycXg] failed to send ping to [{fJor1LC}{fJor1LCXT2GsgCPQcK0QFQ}{69qs2_xyQc-VB09xONjjJQ}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4641857536, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}]
    elasticsearch     | org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [fJor1LC][172.20.0.2:9300][internal:discovery/zen/unicast]
    elasticsearch     | Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action [internal:discovery/zen/unicast]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:36) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:74) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$AuditableTransportRequest.anonymousAccessDenied(AuthenticationService.java:535) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$17(AuthenticationService.java:347) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:352) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:267) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$7(AuthenticationService.java:238) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:256) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$0(AuthenticationService.java:190) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:60) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.TokenService.getAndValidateToken(TokenService.java:313) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$2(AuthenticationService.java:186) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$4(AuthenticationService.java:217) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:228) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:182) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:143) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:113) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.inbound(ServerTransportFilter.java:142) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:314) ~[?:?]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1555) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsExecutors$1.execute(EsExecutors.java:135) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.handleRequest(TcpTransport.java:1512) [elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1382) [elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:64) [transport-netty4-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) [netty-handler-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:545) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    elasticsearch     |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: You also need `xpack.security.enabled=true` in the kibana config

Comment: Hi Val, thanks for the answer. As I was still with the problem I was trying some other things. I tried adding `xpack.security.enabled=true` as you can see in the code that I've just updated above. But the problem continues. Kibana works fine, but no user roles tab under management shows up. Any guees? DOes the code workd for you?

Comment: I see you have your own `kibana.yml` file, can you try to add `xpack.security.enabled=true` in that file instead?

Comment: I had, but I wasn't using it. It was commented the whole document to make sure the parameters in the code above were being used. Nevertheless, I removed it now to test again. I updated the code above you to see the exact code I am using. unfortunately the problem persists. Should I install X-Pack pluguin also in Kibana?

Comment: Can you show the content of the `kibana.yml` file please? And can you try by mapping the kibana config file and removing `xpack.security.enabled=true` from the docker config above?

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhGfm.png

Comment: It doesnt fit here, but basically it was all commented. I wasn't using it.

Comment: Ok, re-map it and simply add `xpack.security.enabled=true` in it and remove `xpack.security.enabled=true` from the docker config file

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understodd right. I added the `xpack.security.enabled=true` to kibana mapping as in the code above. I run again docker.compose on the code above with the `xpack.security.enabled=true` but the problem continues. Should I do anything more?

Comment: In the kibana file it should be `xpack.security.enabled: true` (with `:` not `=`)

Comment: ok, I did it. Update the code above to show both the new code and kibana.yml. I executed it again and same problem

Comment: I also added a picture of what I was expecting to have in Kibana

Comment: Should I have installed X-PACK in Kibana also?

Comment: Can you also share the ES and kibana logs when the container is starting?

Comment: Yes, sure. I updated above with the log

Comment: Hey Val, I restarted Docker today and run the docker-compose script again and an execption seems to be thrown for the security model. Do you know what that means? I added the new log above (not entirely because it didn't fit because of the characters limit)